# EF Database.BeginTransaction Behavior

Tags: entity-framework, transactions

What happens under the following conditions?

```
//Open a transaction
using var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();

// do stuff without calling Commit or Rollback

return;
```

Would this create a db connection in a fault state due to not committing or rolling back the created transaction?

Comment: Without committing, you always roll back the transaction when it is disposed. Sooner or later that will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would this create a db connection in a fault state due to not committing or rolling back the created transaction?

No.  When you Dispose the DbContext the transaction will be rolled back.  If you don't Dispose the DbContext the open connection will sit on the managed heap until it's GC'd at some point in the future, at which point the transaction will be rolled back.  But that could be hours or days.